# Frequency Table. How to get the mean?

Tags: statistics

i don't know what i'm doing wrong, but i'm not getting the answer that is in the text.

---

```
class   Absolute frequency

[0,3)    0

[3,6)    6

[6,9)    7

[9,12)   9

[12,15)  6

[15,18)  1

[18,21)  1
```

I'm getting that the mean is 9.7, but the answer in the text is $\bar{X}=11.95$

Comment: It would probably be helpful to mention which text this comes from.

Comment: is an exercise that gave us the teacher XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your calculation.  You are using the midpoint of each class.  As the classes have a width of $3$, using the top value would only raise it to $11.2$  Tell the teacher the text is wrong and show your calculation.

Comment: I agree that the answer in the text is probably wrong. Even if you take the upper limit of each class the mean is 11.2 which is less than 11.95.